# Android App, Vibrator not working with AlertDialog

Tags: android, media-player, android-alertdialog, vibration

I'm working on my first android app and am having a problem trying to implement the Vibrator. What I'm trying to do is have the AlertDialog display a message, and because the user might not actually have been running the app at the time, play an alarm and vibrate the phone until they close the alert. First I had it working just fine without the vibrator, then when I implemented the vibrator it stopped the alarm sound, and it no longer displayed the AlertDialog. I found out I was able to fix the problem with the alarm by executing it in a new Thread, but still no AlertDialog. So then I tried moving the Vibrator to a new Thread as well and that did not fix my problem. So my current issue is, the phone plays the alarm sound and vibrates, but the AlertDialog I'm telling it to show never gets displayed. How can I get all three of these things working at once? Here is my code (irrelevant parts removed)...

```
public class AlarmDisplayActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer media;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock lock;
    private AlertDialog alert;
    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private Thread vibrateThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.alarmdisplay_screen);

        PowerManager power = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        lock = power.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "AlarmReceiverActivity");
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmDisplayActivity.this).create();
        vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrateThread = new VibrateThread();

        lock.acquire();
        alert.setCancelable(false);

        alert.setButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                media.stop();
                vibrateThread.interrupt();
                lock.release();
            }// Ends onClick
        }// Ends setButton

        startAlarm(this);
        vibrateThread.start();
        alert.show();
    }// Ends onCreate

    private void startAlarm(final Context context) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                if(uri == null) {
                    uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    if(uri == null)
                        uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                }// Ends if

                media = new MediaPlayer();
                try{
                    media.setDataSource(context, uri);
                    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        if(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                            media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                            media.setLooping(true);
                            media.prepare();
                            media.start();
                        }// Ends if
                    }// Ends try
                    catch(Exception e){}
                }// Ends run method
            }.start();
        }// Ends startAlarm method

        class VibrateThread extends Thread {
            public VibrateThread() {
                super();
            }
            public void run() {               
                try {
                    long[] vibPattern = new long[] {0L,100L,250L,1000L,250L,500L};
                    vibrator.vibrate(vibPattern, 2);
                }// Ends try
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }// Ends run method
        }// Ends VibrateThread class

}// Ends AlarmDisplayActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling `startAlarm` is blocking but it is also advised to move all non UI into a different thread. I used AsyncTask to do this and I found it to work really well.

The documentation of AsyncTask you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
because in my app I was fetching from a webservice in my app which blocked the 
whole UI that is probably also happening with your app.

Comment: Well, he uses a Thread, so it doesn't happen in the ui thread